# Meal Time (Conditions)

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

> My goal is a create calculator which takes in times either in 12 or 24-hour format and tells the user, what activity to do.
> #:## am and ##:## am
> #:## pm and ##:## pm

I am getting this error
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'

is x not a string when I compare it and then get converted to a float after that?

This is my code

```
def main():
time = input("What time is it? ")
    if eat(time)>=7.0 and eat(time)<=8.0:
        print("Breakfast")
    elif 0.0>=eat(time)<=1.0:
        print("Lunch")
    elif 6.0 >=eat(time)<=7.0:
        print("Dinner")

def eat(x):
# remove .am and .pm
    if x == x.endswith("am"):
        x = x.replace("am","")
        hours, minutes= x.split(":")
        x = (float(hours)+float(minutes)/60)
        return x
    elif x == x.endswith("pm"):
        x = x.replace("pm","")
        hours, minutes= x.split(":")
        x = (float(hours)+float(minutes)/60)
        return x
main()
```

Comment: It looks like you should review what you've learned earlier, in particular syntax and different types, one more time.

Comment: @molbdnilo Assuming for a moment, that OP struggles with Haskell as we all did, your comment doesn't seem to be particularly helpful. Please help us trying to light the fire of joy, beauty and wisdom in our fellow new Haskellers.

Comment: Needs debugging details. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

Split your task into subtasks:

> Create a high-order function in Haskell that takes in another function.

```
higherOrder :: (a -> b) -> Bool
higherOrder f = undefined  -- a higher order function that takes 
                           -- in another function
```

We have not learned anything about the type of the passed function, which is why we use the placeholder `a -> b`. This will be change later, once we learn more about `f`.

> That second function takes in a list and evaluates to each index to be true or false.

This function is passed in. You don't need to implement it, it will be provided as an argument. You do however need to know its type signature, in this case

```
f :: [a] -> [Bool]  -- a function taking a list of any type
                    -- ([a]), evaluating it to a list of booleans
-- example usage
f [1, 2, 3] == [True, False, True]
```

Which we use to update the type of our `higherOrder`

```
higherOrder :: ([a] -> [Bool]) -> Bool
```

> The high order function should evaluate to true if the second function evaluates to true for at least 2 indexes in the list

You could replace this step with a simpler step: Write a function `atLeastTwo :: [Bool] -> Bool`, that takes a list of Booleans (`[Bool]`) and returns `True` if at least two indexes' values are true.

```
atLeastTwo :: [Bool] -> Bool
atLeastTwo xs = undefined
```

Maybe you can implement `atLeastTwo` by filtering the list, keeping only `True` values and then counting its length. You might find [`filter :: (a -> [Bool]) -> [a] -> [a]`](https://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/filter_f.html) and [`length :: [a] -> Int`](https://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/length_f.html)<sup>1</sup> useful.

Putting it all together you will discover that the task description is not clear. It does not talk about the list that is passed to `higherOrder`. In your case it probably should have been passed as a second parameter (`xs`) so we update `higherOrder` again to

```
higherOrder :: ([a] -> [Bool]) -> [a] -> Bool
higherOrder f xs = undefined
```

### Proposal for an updated assignment

A more natural problem would be, where the passed function processes a list element (`a -> Bool`) instead of a list ( `[a] -> [Bool]`), and would read:

> [Updated/alternative assignment: replacing `([a] -> [Bool])` with `(a -> Bool)`.]
>
> Implement a (higher-order) function `atLeastTwoTrues :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`. The first argument being passed to `atLeastTwoTrues` should be a function that can evaluate a value to either `True` or `False`. The second argument is a list of values. Your function should return `True` if and only if at least two elements of the passed list evaluate to `True` using the first argument.

This would avoid some ambiguity but is a different problem.

Good luck and enjoy your Haskell journey. It is difficult at the start. It has been for all of us. Don't give up, because once you start to master it, you will enjoy it.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is actually not the complete truth since `length` works with more data types than just lists and has a more general type.

```
Prelude> :t length
length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int
```

Comment: It still seems to me that according to the assignment, atLeastTwo should be typed: `atLeastTwo :: ([a] -> [Bool]) -> [a] -> Bool`. I lost that somewhere behind the definition of the function `f`.

Comment: Are you referring to the (original) assignment of `higherOrder`, or my alternative proposal for `atLeastTwo`?

Comment: of course `length` is to be avoided (nearly) always, and instead e.g. `not .  null . drop 2 . filter ....` can be used here. (up to off-by-one error :) )